# TestCafe: User Role logs out the user in the first test

Tags: automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I'm trying to implement User Role in my existing tests as I don't want to login in every tests. Here is what my tests look like:

```
const accountUser = Role('https://localhost:9000', async (t) => {
  await t.wait(1000);
  await loginPage.login(inputData.emailId, inputData.password);
}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture`login-test`
  .meta('testingType', 'regression')
  .requestHooks(mock)

test('Add a person', async (t) => {
  await t.useRole(accountUser);
  await loginPage.goToPeopleList(inputData.testAccountFirst);

test('Unable to add a person', async (t) => {
  await t.useRole(accountUser);
  await loginPage.goToPeopleList(inputData.testAccountFirst);
```

Error:

```
✖ Add a person

   1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('td')
         |   .withText('automation test')

      Browser: Chrome 79.0.3945 / Mac OS X 10.14.6

         258 |  }
         259 |
         260 |  async goToPeopleList(account) {
         261 |    // people list
         262 |    await t
       > 263 |      .click(accountManager.selectTestAccount(account))
```

What happens here is :

- test 1: User is logged in and then fails at `await loginPage.goToPeopleList(inputData.testAccountFirst);` because the user is logged out
- test 2: User is not even logged in and is expecting the already logged in page so it fails at step `await loginPage.goToPeopleList(inputData.testAccountFirst);`

Looked at the troubleshooting [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#troubleshooting) and tried but still it kicks out the logged in user.

I don't know why user is logged out just after this step `await t.useRole(accountUser);`. The authentication token is stored in the cookie after login when I see it manually. At the very least I would expect first test to pass as it already logged in the user.

Comment: Could you please provide a public example that can be used to reproduce and debug the problem or provide access to your website?

Comment: Please note that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If we need to access non-public parts of your website or pass through authorization pages, please ask the website owner to send us (mailto:support@devexpress.com)) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: @AndreyBelym Thanks for your answer. I figured out today that this problem occurs only in my local setup (`https://localhost:9000`) but not in the dev environment, which has URL `https://xx.com` . Would you be able to tell me on how can I debug in my local env to see why it is not able to store the credentials?

Comment: Even If I send you the permission for the dev env then it won't be possible for you to debug as it is not the problem in dev env. Local setup won't be possible for permission

Comment: You can modify the `hosts` file to assign a domain to 127.0.0.1. We can try to check if the issue persists when your production domain name is assigned to your local development server.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBelym . Will talk to my manager and get back to you on this. Until then I made some progress and seems I'm left to resolve 1 last step. In our dev env the cookies are set in the browser but in the local env it is stored in the client. I tried to manually set the cookie while running the tests. It works for the first test but for the next test it kicks out again and even the cookie is there it doesn't redirect to the home page. If I use `t.navigateTo(URL)` then it clears out the cookie. Any idea how could I resolve this. If I'm able to resolve this step then problem is solved.

Comment: The kicking out above happens due the tests are running in a sandbox env but I don't know why it kicks out even when the cookies are there.

Comment: Figured out - So, I'm not using `useRole` for my case in my local env. I'm passing cookies manually. I have to pass `--disable-page-caching` for the above question regarding `t.navigateTo(URL)`