# TestCafe: Web page is unable to navigate to logged in homepage in a docker environment

Tags: javascript, docker, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm manually injecting auth cookie in the browser and trying to keep my user logged in. I'm successfully able to do it in my local environment (not in docker environment). When I run the same test design within a docker environment then the navigation to logged in homepage fails for unknown reasons.

Here is the code:

```
import * as utils from '../../resources/utils';

require('dotenv').config();
const token = process.env.authToken;

fixture`account-test`
  .page(inputData.url)
  .beforeEach(async () => {
    const nextMonth = new Date();
    nextMonth.setMonth(nextMonth.getMonth() + 1);
    console.log(`token value: ${token}`);
    await t.navigateTo(inputData.url).then(await utils.setCookie('AUTH_COOKIE_ID', token, nextMonth));
    console.log('navigation done');
  });

test('Add a new account', async (t) => {
  console.log(await utils.getCookie('AUTH_COOKIE_ID'));
  const accountName = helper.getString();
  console.log(await utils.getCookie('AUTH_COOKIE_ID'));
  await t
    .click(accountManager.addNewAccountButton)
```

Here is the command used to run the tests:

```
docker run --net=host -v `pwd`:/tests -v `pwd`/reporter:/reporters -w /reporters -e userEmail=admin@test.com -e userPass=password -e urlPort=9000 --env-file .env testcafe 'chromium --no-sandbox' '/tests/uitests/**/concurrentTests/accounttest.js' -t 'Add a new account' --disable-page-caching -s takeOnFails=true --reporter 'html:result.html',spec,'xunit:res.xml
```

Here is the output:

```
Running tests in:
 - Chrome 77.0.3865 / Linux 0.0.0

 account-test
token value: 'eyJhbGciOiJSxxxxxxxxxxxNWvTroW0XhR69ZSwGu6PhXnVGOI27h0'
navigation done
'eyJhbGciOiJSxxxxxxxxxxxNWvTroW0XhR69ZSwGu6PhXnVGOI27h0'
'eyJhbGciOiJSxxxxxxxxxxxNWvTroW0XhR69ZSwGu6PhXnVGOI27h0'
     ✖ Add a new account (screenshots:
 /reporters/screenshots/2020-01-16_18-50-54/test-1/Chrome_77.0.3865_Linux_0.0.0/errors/1.png)

   1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('button[aria-label="Add a New Account"]')

      Browser: Chrome 77.0.3865 / Linux 0.0.0
      Screenshot:

   /reporters/screenshots/2020-01-16_18-50-54/test-1/Chrome_77.0.3865_Linux_0.0.0/errors/1.png

         52 |  const accountName = helper.getString();
         53 |  console.log(await utils.getCookie('RP_AUTH_COOKIE_ID'));
         54 |  await t
       > 55 |    .click(accountManager.addNewAccountButton)
         56 |    .typeText(accountManager.accountName, accountName)

         at <anonymous>
      (/tests/uitests/tests/concurrentTests/accounttest.js:55:6)
```

`--env-file .env` this is basically getting the auth token.

Before the test and when in the test I could see the correct AuthToken has been printed but I don't understand even with the correct auth token why it is unable to navigate to the logged in page. The exact same scenario in the local environment (without the TestCafe docker) works perfectly fine. When I don't use the `--disable-page-caching` flag then the auth token return `null` after navigation.

Comment: Did you try to use the TestCafe [User Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) functionality? It is a recommended way to keep a user logged in to TestCafe tests.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me in my local env due to the way my client is setting the cookies instead browser handling the cookies - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631796/testcafe-user-role-logs-out-the-user-in-the-first-test . If you have some solution please do let me know I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: It is difficult to find the cause of this issue without debugging your project. Could you please send us a minimal example so that we can reproduce this behavior?

It's not quite clear what you mean by "it is unable to navigate to the logged in page". The call stack is not related to the login navigation action. The "inputData.url" variable contains your navigation page, doesn't it?

Comment: @VladimirA. - I will again try to reproduce minimal example as I wasn't able to due to lots of dependencies in the project. Yes, `inputData.url === https://localhost:9000` and my login page url is `https://localhost:9000/login`